# Custom settings field error

Tags: apex, error, customsetting, getcontent, variable-names

Although I am having this field in my custom settings it shows Error : Variable does not exist. Please find below code snippet. Can someone let me know what could be the reason?

Code Snippet:

```
FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c userSet;
        if(LoginUserFranchiseName!=null)
        userSet = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);

    FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c  userSet ; //= FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);*/
    if(userSet!=null)
    { Franchise = userSet.Use_Franchise_abv__c;
      if(!Franchise )
      {FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c  userSettings = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserProfileId);}
      else { FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c  userSettings= FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);}
    }
```

System.debug('----->'+userSettings); // This line throws error

Comment: Is second userSet variable declaration a typo? right under userSet = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);

Comment: There's no System.debug call in the code snippet, is there?..

Answer (score 3):

Using consistent code indenting makes code like this and problems like this clearer. Indenting your code results in:

```
FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c userSet;
if(LoginUserFranchiseName!=null) {
    userSet = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);
}

if(userSet!=null) {
    Franchise = userSet.Use_Franchise_abv__c;
    if(!Franchise) {
        FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c  userSettings = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserProfileId);
    } else {
        FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c  userSettings= FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);
    }
} 

System.debug('----->'+userSettings); // This line throws error
```

In Apex, a local variable's scope (whether it can be referenced) is limited to the code block it is in and multi-line code blocks start with `{` and end with `}`. So your `userSettings` variables are not visible where you have added your debug output.

This should avoid the error:

```
if(userSet!=null) {
    Franchise = userSet.Use_Franchise_abv__c;
    FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c userSettings;
    if(!Franchise) {
        userSettings = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserProfileId);
    } else {
        userSettings = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);
    }
    System.debug('----->'+userSettings);
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith tried with your solution. It compiled well but page not loading properly.

Comment: @SFDC_GEEK Usually to get code working you have to first fix compile errors and then logical errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(LoginUserFranchiseName!=null)
FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c userSet = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);
```

What if LoginUserFranchiseName is not null? Then you don't declare userSet at all, do you? So if it is not null, the next if statement is not aware of the variable you are evaluating.

```
if(userSet!=null)
```

To me it should be:

```
FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c userSet;

if(LoginUserFranchiseName!=null)
 userSet = FieldInsightsTrackerSettings_ABV__c.getInstance(LoginUserFranchiseName);
```

I'm assuming here that Franchise variable is declared somewhere outside the given code.